# `input` not being passed to `<Field>`

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I have a component called `RawRadioButton` that doesn't appear to receive the `input` or `meta` objects when I put in on a redux-form. Here's the render method where I call `RawRadioButton`.

```
render() {
  const onForm = this.props.onForm;
  const passThroughProps = {
    name: this.props.name,
    ...
  }

  return (
    <div className={containerClassName}>
      { !onForm && <RawRadioButton {...passThroughProps} /> }
      { onForm && <Field type="radio" component={RawRadioButton} {...passThroughProps} /> }
    </div>
  );
```

When `onForm` is true, I pass the RawRadioButton (the component that draws the input, label, etc) as the component prop on redux-form's `Field` component. In this case, I expect redux-form to pass an `input` and `meta` object which I can use in `RawRadioButton`. Specifically, I'm expecting to see the `name` prop from `RadioButton` show up in `input.name` in `RawRadioButton`.

React devtools show that the `name` prop is making it to the `ConnectedField` that is the direct parent of `RawRadioButton`. So the `ConnectedField` is somehow deciding not to pass this information to `RawRadioButton`. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: No, there is inherently nothing wrong that I can see for the record. Are you sure the Field is in a form context? Maybe it is not picking up the context properly when you switch from !onForm mode to onForm mode...?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This caused me to look at my code again with fresh eyes. The error was in the code I'd replaced with "..." above. I was doing `input: this.props.input`. When input was undefined, it was passing an undefined input to the `Field`, which redux-form gave priority to over the actual input prop.